# how to save Iterator to ES

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I use the partitionBy functions to divide my rdd to multiple partitions, and then I want to put partitions to ES.
EsSpark.saveToEs need rdd, but the partitionBy function leave me the parameter Iterator. Is there a method to save the Iterator to ES or
convert Iterator to rdd？I use the ES-spark 5.2.2
the code is below:

```
var entry = Array("vpn","linux","error")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)

var resultRDD=stream.map( record => {
    val json = parse(record.value())
    val x = json.extract[vpnLogEntry]
    if (!x.innerIP.equals("-")){
      ("vpn",x)
    }else{
      ("linux",x)
    }
})
resultRDD.foreachRDD { (rdd,durationTime) =>
  val entryToIndexDis = rdd.context.broadcast(entry.zipWithIndex.toMap)
  val indexToEntryDis = rdd.context.broadcast(entry.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap)
 rdd.partitionBy(new Partitioner {
    override def numPartitions: Int = entryToIndexDis.value.size
    override def getPartition(key: Any): Int = {
      entryToIndexDis.value.get(key.toString).get
    }
  }).mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, data) => {

    val index_type = indexToEntryDis.value(index)
    //here, I want to put vpn data into vpn/vpn of ES,
    //and put linux data into linux/linux of ES.
    //the variable of data is type of Iterator, 
    //so can not use EsSpark.saveToEs function

    data
  }, true).count()
```

Comment: It would be useful to see some of the code that you currently have. If you're using Scala then you can convert from an Iterator to an array by using .toArray, and then use sc.parallelize() to make an RDD. If you provide some more info I may be able to contribute a full answer

Comment: I have considered your method,  there will be an error "ERROR Utils: Exception encountered
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext" .below is my code: 
      }).mapPartitionsWithIndex((index, data) => {
  
        val index_type = indexToEntryDis.value(index)
        val dir = s"""file:///tmp/${indexToEntryDis.value(index)}/"""
        val fileName = durationTime.milliseconds + "_" + index
        savePartition(dir, fileName, data)

        data
      }, true).count()

Comment: sc is not serializable

Comment: Please can you update your original question with the code? Also the code may have been truncated? It doesn't seem to have a lot of context.

Comment: ok , I have uploaded my code